# Blank page if payment failed in Magento

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway, webshop, msp

I'm setting up a Magento CE webshop, and using the MultiSafePay Plugin for the Payment services.

I'm on a testaccount at the moment, and almost everything is working.
When a payment succeeded, the Payment Gateway is returning to a successpage on my Magento shop: http://domain.com/checkout/onepage/success

But here is the problem, when a payment has failed, it redirects the customer to: http://domain.com/checkout/ which is an empty page. (Only header & footer are visible).

How can I make some error page, so the customer knows his payment failed?
Is this a bug, of human error? Where to start?

Comment: Same problem here, If some magento specialist could answer this... Would be great!